# Using regex to sift through source code tree to find occurrences of a function call

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

Rather than opening a bunch of solution files in VS2010 and then searching for occurrences / references of a function call, I'd rather just grep with a regular expression.  I could do this in two passes -- first grep for all occurrences of `MyFunction()`, then remove all occurrences where it is on a line that is commented out (note: I realize this doesn't handle block comments, and that is okay for now).

I wanted to see if there was a better way to do it, and [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) has an interesting tutorial on positive and negative lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Using my favorite online [regex evaluator](http://regexr.com), I tackled the following examples:

```
  // foo.MyFunction()
foo.MyFunction();
    foo.MyFunction()
//foo.MyFunction()
// { foo.MyFunction(); }
```

but failed miserably.  I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible with negative lookbehinds.  Here's what I thought might work:

```
(?<!//.*)MyFunction\(\)
```

But it doesn't match...  can anyone enlighten me here?

Answer (score 0):

Did the same thing a few times

```
MyFunction\(\)(?<!.*//.*)
```

[Online Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=MyFunction%5C%28%5C%29%28?%3C!.%2a//.%2a%29&i=%20%20//%20foo.MyFunction%28%29%0D%0Afoo.MyFunction%28%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo.MyFunction%28%29%0D%0A//foo.MyFunction%28%29%0D%0A//%20%7B%20foo.MyFunction%28%29;%20%7D)

Comment: regexr has some issues with lookbehind as it's based on javascript which does not support it. I tested it in C# and it works ok

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation... I was just going to ask you because I couldn't get it to work!  :)  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Added a link to an online .NET regex tester in the answer